# <li> <ul> newline

Tags: html, css, newline

So what I need help with, is how do I remove the newline after a `<li>` and or `<ul>`

This is my css:

```
    #ranks li {
    background: url(/img.png) no-repeat top left;
}
#ranks .sprite-admin{ background-position: 0 0; width: 157px; height: 44px; } 
#ranks .sprite-banned{ background-position: -207px 0; width: 157px; height: 44px; }
```

and this is the html:

```
<ul id="ranks"><li class="sprite-admin"></li></ul>
```

It all works well while only one of the `<ul id ="etc">` is there, but if there are multiple, it will make a new line and 'stack' them.. is it possible to make them not stack, and just go left to right?
Thanks

EDIT:

Demo : /removed/

Comment: I'm confused on your question, in your demo, you want the picture sitting beneath the username, but you're asking how you get them side by side

Answer (score 16):

You have a few options:

```
#ranks li {
  float: left;
}
```

This will float all of your list items to the left, without wrapping, until horizontal screen space is no longer available. Alternatively,

```
#ranks li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Which will also put your elements side-by-side, but handle them as bock level elements. If you don't care about block-level styling, you could go with straight inline-display:

```
#ranks li {
  display: inline;
}
```

Which will treat the list items like any other inline element (such as `<span>` or `<a>`).

There are some other inherent styles that exist on list items, as well as their list parent, that you may need to do away with. Be sure to check out `margin`, and `padding`.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/iconud/edit#html,live

#### Look Out Ahead!

You may find that there is an unsightly gap between your list items when they're positioned side-by-side. This is a common problem with inline-lists. One solution is to remove the newline space between closing and opening list item tags:

```
<ul id="ranks"><li>
  Index</li><li>
  Contact</li><li>
  Portfolio</li>
</ul>
```

Or have them all inline, a little less discernible:

```
<ul id="ranks">
  <li>Index</li><li>Contact</li><li>Portfolio</li>
</ul>
```

This is a little tough on the eyes. With HTML, since closing tags aren't always required, you can also leave off the closing tag (though this makes me a bit nervous):

```
<ul id="ranks">
  <li>Index
  <li>Contact
  <li>Portfolio
</ul>
```

#### Multiple Lists Inline Too!

From some of the OP's comments, it appears they might be trying to get not only list items inline, but lists themselves. If that's the case, apply the same aforementioned rules to the lists themselves:

```
#ranks,
#specs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
#ranks li,
#specs li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

Here were have identified two sets of rules using selectors that search for id's, and then tags. You could simplify this by apply a common class to the lists, or by basing the selectors off of a common parent element. Next is the markup:

```
<ul id="ranks">
  <li>Index</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
  <li>Portfolio</li>
</ul>

<ul id="specs">
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Bar</li>
</ul>
```

This results in both lists, and their items, being displayed in a horizontal fashion.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/iconud/2/edit

Comment: You could also use css columns, but that only supports newer browsers, and in some cases is less flexible, so float, or inline(-block) are probably the better choice

Comment: @JoshuaRogers Which example on your page provides the best test case? I can try to work directly with your code to see what solution works best. Also, do you want the `ul` elements to be side-by-side too?

Comment: @JoshuaRogers I don't see anything regarding "snorlax" or "admin" or "coder".

Comment: Okay, add `display: inline-block` to `#ranks`.

Comment: @JoshuaRogers Glad I could help. Please consider accepting this answer to complete this question, and award the both of us reputation.

Answer (score 7):

with some css

```
 <style type="text/css">
 #ranks li { display:block; float:left; }
</style>
```

- updated as comments:  with display:block

Comment: if you question is how to present 'li' elements left to right, that is your answer. Like many others have answered.

Answer (score 1):

`ul li{ display:inline;}` do the trick?

Comment: ya got a bit lazy with the lack of id. Should be something like `#ranks li{display:inline;}`

Answer (score 0):

`<li>` by default is `display:block;`
if you give it `display:inline;` or `diplay:inline-block;` that should remove the linebreak

Comment: Actually, `<li>` by default is [`display: list-item`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html#li-display), not `block`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic example of horizontal UL's

HTML

```
<ul id="list">
    <li class="item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="item">Item 2</li>
    <li class="item">Item 3</li>
</ul>
<span class="clearFloats">
```

​​CSS

```
.item {
    float: left;
}

.clearFloats {
    clear: both;   
}
```

​

​JSFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/peterf/DEUBf/

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to set font-size: 0 in the ul, then restore the desired font-size in the li tags. I prefer this as it's contained within the ul tag, doesn't need further hacks like clear:both, and explains better what the styling is meant to do (hide anything not inside a list item).

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 0;
}
li {
    display: inline-block; /* Or inline, as you like */
    font-size: 16px;
}
```